# What's the best way to resize an FLV without lowering the video quality?

Tags: flash, templates, actionscript-2, flv, streaming-flv-video

I'm making a flash site. And there's a video playing, and it moves around and changes size as the user navigates around the page. I notice when it gets small, the video quality gets bad on it. Any ideas on how to retain its quality, and resize it in a different way?

To note: The video quality was bad when the css for the flash video was set to width and height of 100%. However, when I made it centered, and set it for width and height, it was good, even though it was presented at the same size within the swf. Maybe that same idea could apply within the actionscript?

I'm using as2 for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the `smoothing` attribute to `true` on your `Video` object in ActionScript?

It controls if the video should be smoothed (via interpolation) when it is scaled.

Comment: Yes! You're right. This is what I used:

MovieClip(FLVPlayer.getVideoPlayer(FLVPlayer.activeVideoPlayerIndex))._video.smoothing = true;